# Why won't the terminal change to my shared folders directory?

Tags: command-line, files

I have tried `cd Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads`, but linux does not recognise these directories, No such Directory etc. Why?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using and the error message? Paste it directly from the terminal and not in your own words.

Comment: Have you tried `cd "Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads"` (with the quotation marks around the path)?

Comment: This is a copy of the command and response by terminal parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ cd Desktop/Shared Parellels Folders/Home Downloads
bash: cd: Desktop/Shared: No such file or directory
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory you are trying to `cd` into contains spaces. The shell does not deal with those easily, it stops at the first one and trerats the next sequence of characters as a separate argument. In other words, what you actually ran was:

```
cd Desktop/Shared
```

Which does not exist and the shell complained. To get around this, you need to either escape the spaces with a `\`:

```
cd Desktop/Shared\ Parallels\ Folders/Home/Downloads
```

or to quote the path:

```
cd 'Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads'
```

The above will work if you just open a new terminal because new shell sessions start in your home directory and `Desktop` is a subdirectory of that. If you are in a different directory, you will need to give the full path like so:

```
cd ~/Desktop/Shared\ Parallels\ Folders/Home/Downloads
```

or

```
cd "~/Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads"
```

`~` is just shorthand for your user's home directory. It is the equivalent of `/home/youruser`. However, in order to use that, you need to use double quotes (`"`) else it is treated as a literal `~` and not expanded by the shell.

Comment: I have tried the latter and the response is....parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ cd Desktop/Shared Parellels Folders/Home Downloads
bash: cd: Desktop/Shared: No such file or directory
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ cd ~/Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads
bash: cd: /home/parallels/Desktop/Shared: No such file or directory
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$

Comment: @LouiseAvon sorry, my bad, when using `~/` you need double quotes. You can use `cd "~/Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads"` or `cd '/home/louise/Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads'`. The easiest way though is to use TAB completion, just write `cd ~/Desktop/Shared` and then hit the tab button, it will be expanded automatically..

Comment: I am still getting...parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ cd  "~/Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads"
bash: cd: ~/Desktop/Shared Parallels Folders/Home/Downloads: No such file or directory
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$

Comment: @LouiseAvon in that case, it looks like the directory you are aiming for simply doesn't exist. I just tested by creating the relevant directory and I can `cd` to it with no problem. Try using tab completion as I suggested, also make sure you have your name right, paths are case sensitive. What is the output of `ls ~/Desktop | grep Shared` ?

Comment: I have tried  cd ~/Desktop/Shared [tab].  Nothing at all happens.

Comment: @LouiseAvon you're looking in the wrong place, the directory does not exist. Also, make sure you don't leave a space before hitting the tab button. Please [edit] your question and show us the result of `ls -ld ~/Desktop`. It does not sound like your directory us where you think it is.

Comment: ok, But what does 'ls -ld' represent? I don't understand. I have been assuming that my Shared Parallels Folder is a directory. It seems to be some sort of 'smart' folder. I can not access or browse my Mac files/directories without going into the 'smart' folder on my linux VC. I can access it with my mouse, but not the terminal. I need to use gnome terminal on a saved file on my mac.

Comment: @LouiseAvon um, first of all it represents a mistake on my part, sorry. I meant to write `ls -l ~/Desktop`. That will simply list the contents of your `$HOME/Desktop` directory. Anyway, the issue here is that everything you've told us indicates that the directory you're looking for simply is not where you think it is. I am asking for the contents of your `~/Desktop` directory to make sure.

Comment: Its ok i found out it had a shortcut link >/media/psf folder